# Why am I getting "parameter is missing a value" error after I make the parameter "Hidden" or "Internal"?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

In SSRS, I'm making a report where one parameter is just a placeholder(and the user doesn't touch it). So when I make it  "Hidden" or "Internal" , then I get this error:

```
The 'ClientResponseRange' parameter is missing a value
```

Which is weird to me bec. it was working just fine when it was visible(but totally useless in regards to UI)

Does it have to do with using automatically set parameters(via dataset). ? I've been playing with Internal/Hidden plus the "Null" option...

Comment: This report is deploy to prod or in developemnt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this parameter is not being forced a value.

This parameter needs to be set using a dummy sql that has the other user-selected paramater as one of the inputs. The dummy sql then runs after the user selects the other.

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem,could you please explain how it was solved?